# Weird color behaviour

Tags: materials

new to blender, so pardon me if this is a silly question.

I have two geometries and want them to have the same color , yellow. The color of the object needs to be diffusive , means that I do want the color to be there regardless the lights I have in the scene.

The two geometries have the same material, but they are behaving differently , the
face one is correct, the moon is not.

What I can see is that the face has a yellow color regardless the light while the moon is grayish and turns out yellow only when the light bounces the surface.

Moon has 1 material only
Face has 1 material only
I have removed the garbage and you can see just 1 material per object

[image]
[image]

It's not a camera issue as I not using this models within blender but exported as gtlf and while the face behaves well in both blender and gtlf , moon is yellow only when there is light on both blender and gtlf, so issue is not with the camera or the lights, issue is within the model itself.

[image]

Below the two materials

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Which of those two objects has the correct behavior? What do you have in mind when saying "I want the color to be there regardless the lights"? Please update the explanation :).

Comment: Thanks Michal, updated the question.

Comment: Hi czane,
My answer is short so why don't you try flipping the moon. I saw a yellow part on the other side. A few materials don't work with one side but work with the other. Try flipping the moon on the Y axis. Please try share some more information though. If flipping the moon doesn't work, I would say change the position of your camera. But honestly, I am not very good at diffuse materials.

Comment: @Aster17 thanks updated the question: It's not a camera issue as I not using this models within blender but exported as gtlf and while the face behaves well in both blender and gtlf , moon is yellow only when there is light on both blender and gtlf, so issue is not with the camera or the lights, issue is within the model itself.

Comment: czane, I think I found the problem. Decrease your metallicness for a bit. When metallicness is set to 1 on such objects, it causes problems like this, try changing it to something like 0.95.

Comment: Not sure about end goal of materials in this case, but metallic in almost all cases should be either 0 or 1 (at least in pbr workflow which Blender is using there). I'd try to apply scale for the moon object (object mode > ctrl+a), then in edit mode recalculate normals. It looks to be the reason for difference in shading in viewport

Comment: @MrZak thank you!

Comment: @MrZak correct it now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved via Mr Zak solution:**

I'd try to apply scale for the moon object (object mode > ctrl+a), then in edit mode recalculate normals. It looks to be the reason for difference in shading in viewport

**WHAT DONE:**

Changed Scale

Recalculated normals

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to approach it is to use a flat shader (color shader) without diffuse, the other way is to use the objects' normals in order to create a "fake" light and keep them always consistent regardless the light conditions in your scene (as it is done in most NPR approaches).

this is how a flat shader would look like (just an emission shader in Blender's context)

**Emission Shader (flat)**

[image]

and that's how an NRP would look like

**Dot Product (Geometry Position)**

[image: Dot Product > Position]

or like this

**Dot Product (Geometry Normals)**

[image: Dot Product > Normals]

check the material setup here:

[image]

the second vector in the Dot Product node (math vector) will be  the source of your fake light.

[image]

*Keep in mind that Dot Product gives also negative values, so you may need to clamp it for certain occasions*

Comment: Wow, I never knew dot product exists in node. I know it in calculus. Thanks for this answer and the nodes.

Comment: sure, don't look for a Dot Product, it is just a method in Math Vector node (just clarifying that you wont find a Dot Product node by itself).